# How to call std::function without caring about default parameters

Tags: c++

I have the following scenario:

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
  int a(int x);
  int b(int x, int y=0);
  int c(int x, int y=0, int z=1);
};

int complexInstantiationLogic() {
  return 0;
}

void f(Foo f) {
  auto DoStuff = [&] (std::function<int(Foo&, int)> Fn) {
     return Fn(f, complexInstantiationLogic());
  };
  DoStuff(&Foo::a);
  // This does not work since Foo::b takes two integer arguments, but DoStuff needs a function that takes one integer argument. 
  DoStuff(&Foo::b); 
  // This does not work since Foo::c takes three integer arguments, but DoStuff needs a function that takes one integer argument. 
  DoStuff(&Foo::c); 
}
```

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible? I am currently using `std::function` in my lambda, but I am open to using a different approach.

Comment: A default parameter means if the callsite gives `c(5);` the compiler uses the defaults `c(5, 0, 1);`  But the compiler **cannot** do that when using a function pointer, because it doesn't know that the function pointer will be used to that particular function.  Also, the parameters are part of the function's **signature** (`fn(int)` ≠ `fn(int, int)` ≠ `fn(int, int, int)`).

Comment: Default arguments are substituted at the call site.   They are not part of the function signature, so it is not possible to pass the default arguments via a function pointer - which means the information is not available when the function pointer is dereferenced (used to call the function).  Similar argument goes for template-based wrappers (e.g. `std::function`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments are substituted at the call site. They are not part of the function signature, so it is not possible to pass the default arguments via a function pointer - which means the information is not available when the function pointer is dereferenced (used to call the function).  The same argument goes for wrappers of a function pointer (e.g. `std::function`).

The closest you can come is to *overload* the functions instead of using default arguments.  For example;

```
struct Foo {
   int a(int x);
   int b(int x, int y);
   int b(int x) {return b(x, 0);};
   int c(int x, int y, int z);
   int c(int x, int y) {return c(x,y,1);};
   int c(int x) {return c(x, 0, 1);};    // alternative:  return c(x, 0);
};
```

This doesn't eliminate repetition as neatly as you would probably like, but does localise that repetition to the definition of the functions being called rather than requiring the caller to somehow supply the defaulted values.

Since the functions now have overloads, the type system comes into play to help to help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I think you explain it very well that optional params are passed at the call site. Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to modify `Foo` like this, and I'll probably just have to write my code without the lambda to help simplify things.

Comment: @yasgur99   Another option is to write a class (say) `FooWrapper` that privately contains a `Foo`, and provides the member functions as above, and implement them to call corresponding member functions of the contained `Foo`.   Then use `FooWrapper` instead of `Foo` directly.   Can't get away from needing to write more code than you would like, but at least you only need to write it once (for each class like `Foo`).

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are used and passed when a function is called. `DoStuff(&Foo::b)` - this is not a call. Lambda may help

```
DoStuff([](Foo& f, int x) { return f.b(x); });
DoStuff([](Foo& f, int x) { return f.c(x); });
```

Comment: This eliminates any use the lambda was going to have at simplifying redundant code. Now, I could remove DoStuff and do direct calls to `f.b(x); and f.c(x);`

Comment: @yasgur99, we may need to know more about your real use-case to work out which solution is going to scale better? You could wrap each method up like `const auto FooC = [](Foo& f, int Arg1){ return f.c(Arg1); };` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/feTK5Pndv). Would that work?